# How to understand flip intuitively?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

In MMP, when we get a small extremal contraction $f:X\rightarrow Y$, we will flip it to $f^+:X^+\rightarrow Y$ such that $K_{X^+}+D^+$ is $f^+$-ample. Technically, I understand that is because we want to avoid small contractions which destroy $\mathbb Q$-factorial property. But I don't know if there is a more natural way to understand it.

My Questions:

1. Geometrically, what does the birational map $\phi:X\dashrightarrow X^+$ look like?
2. Is there any direct relation between the 'convex cone diagrams' of $X$ and $X^+$?
3. Flip seems to be a very symmetric operation. So why could we expect things to become better after flip? For example, is that possible when we flip twice, we get back to the original one?